# What tools do you use to profile (native)C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, profiling

How do Window's programmers profile their native C++ code?
On Unix/Linux you have gprof *[thanks Evan]* & valgrind (I personally used this one, although it's not a real profiler), and recently I'm on Mac and Solaris, which means I moved to dTrace. Now when I've had the need to profile on Windows in the past, like at my previous job, I used Intel's vtune, which is great, however it's commercial, and I don't have a license for private use, so I'm left wondering what's the standard (free is better) tool windows programmers commonly use?

Thanks in advance

Comment: valgrind is more of an error finding tool. gprof is the profiling tool of choice for the GNU toolchain.

Comment: @Evan: Boy, if **gprof** is the tool of choice, we've got a long way to go. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should give [Xperf](http://blogs.msdn.com/pigscanfly/archive/2008/02/09/xperf-a-new-tool-in-the-windows-sdk.aspx) a try - it's a new system wide performance tool that can drill down to a particular application and what exactly it's doing inside itself as well as what's it's asking of the OS.

It's freely available on the [Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5 ISO](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF&displaylang=en):

> 1. Install the SDK by downloading the [ISO image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF&displaylang=en), or using the Web based
>      installer.
> 2. Find the xperf MSI in the SDK's "bin" directory.   It will be named
>      xperf_x86.msi, xperf_x64.msi, or
>      xperf_ia64.msi, depending on the
>      architecture for which you install the
>      SDK.
> 3. You can then install the xperf tools from the MSI directly, or copy
>      the xperf MSI file to another location
>      and install it from there.  For
>      example, you could keep the MSI files
>      on a USB key.

[Source: Pigs Can Fly blog on MSDN.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/pigscanfly/archive/2008/02/09/xperf-a-new-tool-in-the-windows-sdk.aspx)

Just verified that the xperf msi will not install except on windows Vista or Windows 2007.

-Adam

Comment: Looks interesting indeed, now I only need to migrate to Vista... bet it could run on XP, but they just want to attract people to switching to Vista... anyways +1 and thanks

Answer (score 3):

I got [AMD Code Analyst](http://www.amd.com/codeanalyst/).  It's free, and you don't need an AMD CPU ;)

It's a little basic compared to something like Intel's VTune, but the price is right.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) talks about Linux, but I use the same technique in MSVC and in C#.